# Jquery Ajax - Not loading text

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am new to jquery and coding in general. This is what I am trying to do:

- When a link is clicked, expand the #country_slide div
- Show "loading" text
- If ajax is successful, put the contents of an html file into the div
- Otherwise alert an error and close the div

This is the code I now have:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/n9nVs/5/

```
window.onload = function () {
    var a = document.getElementById("country_link");
    a.onclick = function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/ajax/test.html',
            timeout: 5000,
            beforeSend : function() {
                $("#country_slide").show();
                $("#country_slide").val('<p>Loading</p>')
            }, 
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#country_slide").html(data);
                alert('request successful');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed');
                $("#country_slide").hide();
            },
            complete : function() {
               $('.loader').hide();
            }, 
        });
        return false;
    }
}
```

When the link is clicked, I never see the loading text in the box. Please can someone tell me where I have gone wrong here? Also if anyone can offer any words of advice about my first jquery script I would really appreciate it.

Comment: You don't have any element with `id="country_link"`.

Comment: `.val()` is for setting the value of a form input. Use `.html()` to set the HTML content of an element.

Comment: You have two spans with the same ID `strong`. IDs have to be unique. I suspect you meant for this to be a class, or maybe you meant `<strong>`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n9nVs/12/ with your needed changes =)

Comment: one more thing, that is not related to the question so much, but still important. Avoid using jquery selectors like `$("#country_slide").show();
 $("#country_slide").val('<p>Loading</p>')`. Cache object instead:`$countrySlide = $("#country_slide"); $countrySlide.show();
$countrySlide.val('<p>Loading</p>')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n9nVs/15/)**

- You don't have any `country_link` element in your page.
- Instead of using `window.onload` you can use DOM ready.
- Attach click handler by jQuery with `.on()` method.
- The `.val()` method is for `<input />`. For other elements, use `.html()` instead.

---

```
// DOM ready instead of window.onload
$(function () {
    // attach click handler by jQuery instead of onclick
    $('#country').on('click', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/ajax/test.html',
            timeout: 5000,
            beforeSend : function() {
                $("#country_slide").show();
                // val() method is for <input />
                // use html() instead
                $("#country_slide").html('<p>Loading</p>')
            }, 
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#country_slide").html(data);
                alert('request successful');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed');
                $("#country_slide").hide();
            },
            complete : function() {
               $('.loader').hide();
            }, 
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

References:

- [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) - jQuery API Documentation
- [`jQuery( callback )`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) - jQuery API Documentation

Answer (score 4):

Your anchor's id is `country`, not `country_link`. So:

```
var a = document.getElementById("country");
```

or just use jQuery's id selector:

```
var a = $("#country");
```

or even better directly chain:

```
$(function() {
    $('#country').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/ajax/test.html',
            timeout: 5000,
            beforeSend : function() {
                $("#country_slide").show();
                $("#country_slide").html('<p>Loading</p>')
            }, 
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $("#country_slide").html(data);
                alert('request successful');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed');
                $("#country_slide").hide();
            },
            complete : function() {
               $('.loader').hide();
            }, 
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Notice that I have used the `$(document).ready` function instead of `window.onload`. Also I have replaced the `onclick` event subscription with jQuery's `click` function. If you are using jQuery it would be better to take full advantage of it.

Comment: You don't use `.onclick` with jQuery objects.

Comment: Good point @Barmar, thanks. I have updated my answer to take it into account.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't seem to get your example working though, any clues? http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/n9nVs/19/

Comment: See my updated answer. You should use `$('#country').click(function() { ... });`

Comment: Sorry Darin I used the new code and still nothing? http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/n9nVs/21/

Comment: That's because now you changed the id back to `country_link` in your anchor!!! Please be consistent in your naming conventions. The id of your anchor must match your selector otherwise you are not attaching any click event to this element.

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no element with an ID `country_link`

`document.getElementById()` returns null if the element isn't found

```
document.getElementById('country').onclick = ...; //should work
```

In JavaScript, `null` is a special primitive and you cannot add properties to primitive types.

Answer (score 2):

On the fiddle you have

```
<a href="#" id="country">
```

Where it should be:

```
<a href="#" id="country_link">
```

or change the JS to be

```
var a = document.getElementById("country");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use plain JS if you already have jQuery (it will be easier for you):

```
;$(document).ready(function(){
    $(country_link).click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html',
            url: '/ajax/test.html',
            timeout: 5000,
            beforeSend : function() {
                $(country_slide).show();
                $(country_slide).val('<p>Loading</p>');
            }, 
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                $(country_slide).html(data);
                alert('request successful');
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('request failed');
                $(country_slide).hide();
            },
            complete : function() {
               $('.loader').hide();
            }, 
        });
        return false;
    });
  });
```

Comment: `$(country_link)` is not right, it should be `$("#country_link")`, except that there's no such element in his HTML.

Comment: I guess it works, but it's not the idiomatic way -- I noticed you used `$("#...")` for all your other ID selectors.

Comment: Every other id reference was on the original script, but of course $("#country_link") is also a working solution.

Comment: I've changed the id references, so it won't be mixed in the script

Answer (score 0):

You have to add an element with id=country_link and the this code will work as NOX said. I have tried that in jsfiddle. try it using

```
$("#country").click(function(){
// your code goes here

})
```

that will works.

Answer (score 0):

1. `document.getElementById("country_link");` shall be replaced by `document.getElementById("country");` as `"country_link"` is not the `id` of any `<a>` tag in the mark up.
2. If you are using `jQuery` library you may handle event like-

   ```
   $(document).on("click","a",function(){
       //ajax stuff
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Updated Your jsfiddle Code. Just check. its going to failure method. In your workspace you should have the test.html returning the actual data. Thanks.